# How can I improve this mobile site?

Tags: html, css

I have a site which I want to make mobile. I just started with mobile.
How can I improve this site ?

Is there a way I can use css to position an element when a condition is met like for instance when the width is smaller then a certain limit. I center an elemtn?

Here is the link to the jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/SNFCd/

```
#bk-parent{width:90%; background-color:black; margin:0 auto; font-family: sans-serif; color:white}
#bk-header{width:inherit}
.logo {float:left;}
.addr{float:right}
#bk-footer li{float:left}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want are [Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/). That link is for the W3C recommendations.

Basically, the syntax is as follows:

```
@media only screen and (min/max-width: ){ 
  //do something

}
```

These are called 'break points'. Which means, at the point where the browser reaches the min/max width you provide, you can overrule any other css. So, you can indeed center the element when that condition is met.

```
@media screen and (min/max-width: ){ 

  div {
      margin: 0 auto;
   }


}
```

[Smashing Magazine](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/) also provides a good (IMO) tutorial on them.

Answer (score 2):

I think `media queries` are what you are after

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) { code for small screens}
```

[Random Blog post](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/)